# How do I create object from multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So let's say I have 2 arrays

```
keyword = ['test','123']
lang = ['en','fr']
```

From these two, I want to create an object from `keyword` that contains each `lang`. Like below

```
keywords = [
    {
      keyword: "test",
      lang: "en",
    },
    {
      keyword: "test",
      lang: "fr",
    },
    {
      keyword: "123",
      lang: "en",
    },
    {
      keyword: "123",
      lang: "fr",
    },
  ];
```

So in total I'll have 4 objects cause each keyword will have their own lang. I've tried mapping but it's just not possible once I have 1 keyword and 2 languages.

Comment: _"it's just not possible"_. It is, you can map twice. First map the keywords and then the langs

Comment: Related: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/8746648)

Comment: I tried to find related question but can't find it. Prolly cause I didn't use the "cartesian" keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a nested loop:

```js
const keywords = [];
for (const k of keyword) {
  for (l of lang) {
    keywords.push({ keyword: k, lang: l });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two maps, with the outer one being a [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) so you don't have nested arrays:

```js
const keyword = ['test', '123']
const lang = ['en', 'fr']

const keywords = keyword.flatMap(key => lang.map(language => ({
  keyword: key,
  lang: language
})))

console.log(keywords)
```

Answer (score -1):

Oneliner

```
const keywords = keyword.map(k => lang.map(l => ({ keyword: k, lang: l }))).flat();
```

=>

```
[
   {
      keyword: 'test1',
      lang: 'en'
   },
   {
      keyword": 'test1',
      lang: 'fr'
   },
   {
      keyword": '123',
      lang: 'en'
   },
   {
      keyword": '123',
      lang: 'fr'
   }
]
```

Comment: i was gonna go with this but the returned array is not like what I wanted
it retuned arrays of array like `[ [ {...} , {...} ], [{...}, {...} ] ]`

Comment: Hey @Ilmi sorry, didn't notice this comment. Forgot `.flat()` at the end, now it should be fine ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here you are, just utilized map() and reduce() to implement what you need.

If you need a further explanation, please let me know.

```js
const keywordArr = ['test','123']
const langArr = ['en','fr']

function makeKeywords(keywords, langs) {
    return keywords.reduce((acc, keyword) => [...acc, ...langs.map(lang => ({keyword, lang}))], []);
};

console.log(makeKeywords(keywordArr, langArr));
```